# Language Mixing: Model and View

Tags: c++, iphone, cocoa-touch, boost, objective-c++

Consider developing an application where the model will be written in C++ (with Boost), and the view will be written in Objective-C++ (with Cocoa Touch).

Where are some examples showing how to integrate C++ and Objective-C++ for developing iPhone applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take it straight from the source: Apple has documentation on [using C++ With Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html).

There really isn't much more to it besides, in my opinion, trying to keep the C++ and Objective-C parts as cleanly seperated as possible.

In your case it comes natural:

- limit definition of C++ classes et al to the C++ model
- restrict the Objective-C part to the view related code and using the C++ model

I don't know of any actual simple examples, but any cross-platform project that has a native GUI on the mac uses the same approach. One mostly clean example would be the [Chromium source](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/).