# How to compile c++ in xCode for your IPhone app?

Tags: c++, iphone, ios4

I am doing my first steps in IPhone developing. I want to use some c\c++ code but I can't find any reference of how it's done (will very appriciate if you can also refer me to your source when you give an answear)

I have a file called calc.h containing a "calculator" class with simple add and mult functions, I imported it exactly as I did with an Objective-C header file. What am I suppose to do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you were doing when you were coding just in C/C++.

For example:

```
#include "calc.h"
....
-(void) testCode { //obj-c
 float x = 3;
 float y = 8.0;
 float sumOfTwo = sum(x, y);
}
```

Assuming that you have a function named sum in your header file similar with the one used above.

Comment: I did exactly that with objective c header files. The difference is that I have a class in the c++ file. How do I address a function in the class?
Will appriciate if you can also refer me to a source where I can read about this.

Comment: 1. Rename your .m file to .mm 2. Create an object of that class type as you do it normally in c++. 3. Call a method on that object. Again, nothing special except for the file name. http://www.macresearch.org/objective_c_for_objective_c_programmers and http://gavmacprogramming.wordpress.com/2007/04/26/c-for-objc-programmers-part-i/

Answer (score 0):

If you use standard extensions for the source files (e.g. `.cpp` / `.c`) you can simply build them without doing anything special.
If you use uncommon extensions you need to set the file type manually: In *File* → *Get Info* set *File Type* to *sourcecode.cpp.cpp* / *sourcecode.c.c*.

Note however that you can't use C++ in plain Objective-C (`.m`) files - if you want to do that you need to use [Objective-C++](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH10-SW1) (`.mm`) instead.
For using C there is no such restriction as Objective-C is a superset of C - as with C++ you may need to watch out for uses of identifiers that are keywords in Objective-C though.

Comment: Can you refer me to a source discussing this issue?

Comment: @Gal: There is a link to the Apple Objective-C++ discussion in my answer. For related problems see [here](http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-c-take-2-1-486), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885586/language-mixing-model-and-view/1885649), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226912/can-i-separate-c-main-function-and-classes-from-objective-c-and-or-c-routines-a/2227013), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746215/c-reference-type-as-instance-variable-in-objective-c/2746250), ...